# XmlTextReader() identificar final de nó e tags duplicadas

Tags: c#, xml

**1 - Como identificar tags iguais com nós diferentes?** ex: `Categoria` dentro de `Dados` e `Formato`

**2 - Como identificar que acabou um produto e começou outro?**

Tenho o XML (fictício):

```
<produtos>
  <produto>
    <id>1</id>
    <dados>
       <categoria>teste</categoria>
    </dados>
    <formato>
    <categoria>teste2</categoria>
    </formato>
  </produto>
  <produto>
    <id>2</id>
     ...
  </produto>
</produtos>
```

NO C#

```
var produtos = new List<produto>();
var produto = new produto();
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader("aquivo.XML"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            if (reader.Name == "ID")
            {
                produto.ID = reader.ReadString();
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "categoria") //?? 
            {
                produto.Dados.categoria = reader.ReadString();
            }
            else if (reader.Name == "categoria") //??
            {
                produto.Formato.categoria = reader.ReadString();
            }
        }
    //Final de produto
    produtos.Add(produto);
    }
}
```

Ele está lendo os dados corretamente, mas não sei como identificar o final de um produto e entender em qual tag, pai ele está.

OBS: Não queria fazer em XMLDocument ou outro formato, pois já tenho bastante do código já funcionando. mudar seria apenas em último caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML é uma estrutura com vários níveis, e você está tentando ler de forma "flat". O que você está fazendo é basicamente a deserialização do XML para os seus objetos C#, e a melhor maneira de fazer isso é usar uma classe de serialização (por exemplo, [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) ou [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Agora, se você realmente quer fazer o trabalho "na mão" (e eu não aconselho, já que a chance de você ter erros na sua implementação não é desprezível) você precisa armazenar o contexto de onde os nós aparecem. Uma possibilidade é armazenar todos os antecedentes dos nós, e usar essa informação, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Program
{
    const string XML = @"<produtos>
                          <produto>
                            <id>1</id>
                            <dados>
                               <categoria>cat dados 1</categoria>
                            </dados>
                            <formato>
                            <categoria>cat formato 1</categoria>
                            </formato>
                          </produto>
                          <produto>
                            <id>2</id>
                            <dados>
                               <categoria>cat dados 2</categoria>
                            </dados>
                            <formato>
                            <categoria>cat formato 2</categoria>
                            </formato>
                          </produto>
                        </produtos>";

    static void Main()
    {
        Stack<string> pilha = new Stack<string>();
        var produtos = new List<Produto>();
        var produto = new Produto { Dados = new Dados(), Formato = new Formato() };
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(XML)))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "ID")
                    {
                        produto.ID = reader.ReadString();
                    }
                    else if (reader.Name == "categoria")
                    {
                        var topoDaPilha = pilha.Peek();
                        if (topoDaPilha == "dados")
                        {
                            produto.Dados.Categoria = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                        else if (topoDaPilha == "formato")
                        {
                            produto.Formato.Categoria = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
                    {
                        pilha.Push(reader.Name);
                    }
                }
                else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                {
                    pilha.Pop();
                    if (reader.Name == "produto")
                    {
                        produtos.Add(produto);
                        produto = new Produto { Dados = new Dados(), Formato = new Formato() };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Produtos:");
        foreach (var prod in produtos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- {0}", prod);
        }
    }
}

class Produto
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Dados Dados { get; set; }
    public Formato Formato { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Produto[ID={0}, Dados/Cat={1}, Formato/Cat={2}]", ID, Dados.Categoria, Formato.Categoria);
    }
}
class Dados
{
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
}
class Formato
{
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Uma outra possibilidade é aceitar a recursividade do XML, e usar funções para ler cada parte do seu documento:

```
class Program
{
    const string XML = @"<produtos>
                          <produto>
                            <id>1</id>
                            <dados>
                               <categoria>cat dados 1</categoria>
                            </dados>
                            <formato>
                            <categoria>cat formato 1</categoria>
                            </formato>
                          </produto>
                          <produto>
                            <id>2</id>
                            <dados>
                               <categoria>cat dados 2</categoria>
                            </dados>
                            <formato>
                            <categoria>cat formato 2</categoria>
                            </formato>
                          </produto>
                        </produtos>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var produtos = new List<Produto>();
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(XML)))
        {
            reader.ReadToDescendant("produto");
            while (reader.IsStartElement("produto"))
            {
                produtos.Add(ReadProduto(reader));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Produtos:");
        foreach (var produto in produtos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("- {0}", produto);
        }
    }

    static Produto ReadProduto(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Debug.Assert(reader.LocalName == "produto");
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            // Vazio, não tem filhos. Avança pro próximo nó e retorna
            ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);
            return produto;
        }

        ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);

        do
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "id")
                {
                    produto.ID = reader.ReadString();
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);
                }
                else if (reader.Name == "dados")
                {
                    produto.Dados = ReadDados(reader);
                }
                else if (reader.Name == "formato")
                {
                    produto.Formato = ReadFormato(reader);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("No do XML nao reconhecido");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);
            }
        } while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement);

        Debug.Assert(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement);
        ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader); // avança pro próximo produto ou fim

        return produto;
    }

    static Dados ReadDados(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Debug.Assert(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element);
        Debug.Assert(reader.LocalName == "dados");
        Dados dados = new Dados();
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            // Vazio, não tem filhos. Avança pro próximo nó e retorna
            ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);
            return dados;
        }

        do
        {
            ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "categoria")
            {
                dados.Categoria = reader.ReadString();
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) reader.Read();
            }
        } while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement || reader.Name != "dados");

        Debug.Assert(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement);
        ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader); // avança pro próximo produto ou fim

        return dados;
    }

    static Formato ReadFormato(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Debug.Assert(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element);
        Debug.Assert(reader.LocalName == "formato");
        Formato formato = new Formato();
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            // Vazio, não tem filhos. Avança pro próximo nó e retorna
            ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);
            return formato;
        }

        do
        {
            ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader);
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "categoria")
            {
                formato.Categoria = reader.ReadString();
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) reader.Read();
            }
        } while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement || reader.Name != "formato");

        Debug.Assert(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement);
        ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(reader); // avança pro próximo produto ou fim

        return formato;
    }

    static bool ReadToNextElementOrEndElement(XmlReader reader)
    {
        do
        {
            if (!reader.Read()) return false;
        } while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement);
        return true;
    }
}

class Produto
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Dados Dados { get; set; }
    public Formato Formato { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Produto[ID={0}, Dados/Cat={1}, Formato/Cat={2}]", ID, Dados.Categoria, Formato.Categoria);
    }
}
class Dados
{
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
}
class Formato
{
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: gostei mais da primeira forma e realmente você tem razão eu já imaginava que utilizando o XMLtoReader a chance de dar um problema na leitura é grande, visto que praticamente leio ele como se fosse um texto. vou estudar sobre o XmlSerializer para ver se ele ajuda nesse quesito. Porém meu código já está ficando complexo demais..rs

Answer (score 2):

Esse é o jeito difícil de desserializar um XML de produtos.

Pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
[XmlRoot("produtos")]
public class ListaProdutos
{
    [XmlElement("produto")]
    public List<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dados")]
    public Dados Dados { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("formato")]
    public Formato Formato { get; set; }
}

public class Dados
{
    [XmlElement("categoria")]
    public String Categoria { get; set; }
}

public class Formato
{
    [XmlElement("categoria")]
    public String Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Uso:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListaProdutos));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(stringComXml))
{
    var resultado = (ListaProdutos) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Hum essa pode ser uma boa dica, porém e se o XML não for padronizado? ou seja, alguns campos não virem preenchido ou com uma pequena mudança de estrutura? eu teria um erro ou ele processaria?

Comment: A estratégia é formular a estrutura de classes da forma mais abrangente possível. Ou seja, suponha que cada nó venha completamente preenchido. O serializador saberá o que fazer.